# Не могу выбрать медиа запрос

Tags: css, media-queries

Ку ребятки, начал изучать медиа запросы и наткнулся на два синтаксиса.
После этого у меня возник вопрос:

В первом способе нету screen, а во втором он есть. Зачем писать screen, как во втором способе, если результат у обоих способов один и тот же

**1 способ** - такой подход использует Bootstrap.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

**2 способ** - я скопировал из Mozilla.org.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Могу ли я выбрать первый способ, так как он короче второго. **Ведь оба этих синтаксиса приведут же к одному результату?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Содержимое этого блока будет применяться при достижении ширины экрана менее 992 пикселя.

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
```

Содержимое этого блока будет применяться только для экранов и при достижении ширины экрана менее 992 пикселя.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
```

Более подробную информацию о типах (как `screen`) можно посмотреть на [сайте Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media#media_types).

Comment: Получается, что между 1 и 2 способом разницы нет, так как результат будет один и тот же? И можно выбрать первый способ от Bootstrap, дабы сократить код. Я все правильно понял?

Comment: @Зеленыйчел, разница есть, но только если необходимо делать отдельные стили для экрана, скрин ридера и т.д.

Comment: В одной теме я вычитал, что можно писать @media без screen, типа результат будет одинаков.

Comment: @Зеленыйчел, для отображения контента на экране — да, результат будет одинаков. Опять же, контент может выступать не только для отображения на экране. Если на вашей странице не подразумевается поддержка прочих типов `@media` — можете действительно просто не писать тип, или писать тип `all`.

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы когда условие (min-width: 992px) было верно, то мои стили работали на ПК, телефоне и планшете. К примеру смена цвета фона, увеличение шрифта и т.д.  @media (min-width: 992px) с таким синтаксисом все это будет ли работать? Или нужен другой синтаксис?

Comment: @Зеленыйчел, такое условие будет работать с обоими вариантами написания `@media`

Comment: На телефонах и планшетах будет работать? Зачем вообще писать screen?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Прочитал, там не сказали, когда можно писать screen, а когда нет =)

Comment: @Зеленыйчел, более подробную информацию можно так же прочитать на странице https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries